# Disable with select2 does not work.

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angularjs-select2

I'm using version 3.5.1. I've tried using both

```
enable: false
```

and

```
disable: true
```

but neither seems to work. 
Here's a snippet of my code.

```
  var select2Node = $element[0].firstChild;
  $(select2Node).select2({
    data: choices,
    // Suppress the search box.
    minimumResultsForSearch: -1,
    allowClear: false,
    width: '200px',
    disable: true,
    formatSelection: function(object, container) {
      return $filter('truncateAtFirstInput')(object.id);
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is an "enable" or "disable" option for the Select2 constructor. Instead, you can use the "enable" function, like this:

```
$(select2Node).select2({
    ...
}).select2("enable", false);
```